# How to check which user triggered a signal?

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-1.8

I have a simple signal in my project, that checks which fields have been updated in the form. I also need to check the user who changed data in those fields.

Request.user doesn't seem to work here.

```py
@receiver(sender=BackOperator, signal=pre_save)
def change_log(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    try:
        original_object = BackOperator.objects.using('operator').get(pk=instance.pk)
    except:
        return
    if original_object:
        field_names = [field.name for field in original_object._meta.fields]

        for field in field_names:
            try:
                ori_field = getattr(original_object, field)
                new_field = getattr(instance, field)
                message = (field + ": " + str(ori_field) + " changed to: " + str(new_field))
                if ori_field != new_field:
                    BackNote.objects.using('operator').\
                        create(operator=instance.pk, note=message)
            except:
                return
```

I'd like to add a user's username as a string to message, that is saved in the BackNote table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several options:

1. Include a FK to `User` on `BackOperator`. Ex: `LastAccessByUser=models.ForeignKey(User ...` Fill `LastAccessByUser` on your views.
2. Use a package like [django-currentuser](https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/) to access current user.

For me, the first solution is cleaner than second one, that looks like an **anti pattern**.

Comment: Looks reasonable, but I'd like to avoid adding further columns to BackOperator.

Comment: @ZmuA: option 2. ;)